# PointToScreen method returns diffrent values on identical monitors

Tags: c#, wpf

On one monitor I do this and get the following:

```
initial_point = (double)Studio.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)).X; // returns 107
final_point = (double)(Btn_Import.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)).X); //returns 406
```

on another monitor that has the exact same size and resolution, I run the following code but get different values:

```
initial_point = (double)Studio.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)).X; // returns 133
final_point = (double)(Btn_Import.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d)).X); // returns 507
```

SO I get different differences of initals and final points on two identical monitors, which causes wrong translation distance of some gui controls. Why does this happen?

Comment: The monitors have same resolution in system or same resolution build in ?

Comment: The difference is exactly 125%.  That [ought to look familiar](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/253770d1360038932-dpi-display-size-settings-change-w7-display.jpg).